# how to run ant script from one machine targeting another machine?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have do the following using the Ant.
I need to run the ant script from machine A, the script has the details about the machine B like host name, username, pwd, directory to download, ftp details etc and When the script ran from machine A it should download the somefile using ftp in machine B.

I have given the details about the machine B in script, but when i ran the script it downloads the file in machine A instead of machine B. what i'm missing? or can some one help me with the code?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

In maven i have defined the machine B details:

```
<host>MachineB</host>
<host.username>user</host.username>
<host.password>pwd</host.password>
```

In build.xml

```
<target name="Todownload_file" <mkdir dir="${download_dir}" />

    <ftp action="get" server="download_server_details" userid="user" password="pwd" remotedir="path">
        <fileset dir="${download_dir}">
            <include name="${file_name}"/>
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

As i said in the comments, there is no link between the machine b details and the ftp download section. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Is this what you are asking "Running the ant script from machine A. You want the script to download the file from B to A."? From what you describe that's what's happening.

Comment: Are you using something like sshexec? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html

Comment: post the relevant parts of your ant script (removing actual host, user and pwd). Specifically the part that FTPs the file.

Comment: Hi KM1, actually i need to run script from machine A which should download some file in machine B. Like wise later i will enhance the code to point to different machine and download the file

Comment: Hi Gilberto, I didnt give a try with sshexec. Thanks for the link and will give a try

Comment: Hi Km1 - Yeah i can post the code. But to be frank, i didnt link the machine B details with the FTP download details. thats why the code download's the file from where it has ran. Any thoughts on linking the machine details with the ftp details>?

Comment: I don't understand what's going on, so I am voting to close as it seems confusing what the expected behavior is. Also, I removed the maven tag since there is no mention of maven.

Comment: Hi Tim, I apologizes if expected behaviour confuses you. In Simple I need to run script from the machine A, the script will have details of different machine details and about the ftp details. When the script ran from machine A, it should download files into differnet machines. Hope this clarifies you.

Comment: Btw the script can be from maven or from ant too or combination of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sshexec task to run remote commands and you can use sep to copy/push files from/to machine B. There are a few ways you could do this conceptually.

First approach:
Download the file from the remote ftp site onto machine A then copy it to Machine B using the scp task. Finally run the file on machine B using sshexec.

Second approach:
Download the file directly onto Machine B by running the curl or ftp commands directly on Machine B from Machine A via sshexec. Then run another sshexec task to execute the file on Machine B.

Third approach:
Write a script (workflowscript.sh) that would work on Machine B (bash for Mac/Linux powershell/VBScript for Windows) and in this script you put the logic to perform the download of the other script via ftp or curl or whatever. Use scp on Machine A to copy workflowscriipt.sh to Machine B then use sshexec to execute it.

In all above approaches you need to be aware of what runs where. Machine A just pushes files or sends remote commands to machine B and machine B does all the work.

Comment: thanks cliff. I like the second approach. since the file which am going to download in machine B is executable file, so as you stated I can use another sshexec task to execute the file.

Comment: Right, you could also string the download and execute step together in one call to sshexec. "curl http://someserver.com/path/file > executable; chmod +x executable; ./executable" I added chmod to be certain the exec bit is set and I always add "./" before the call to the executable because not all Linux/Unix hosts have the current working directory "." included in their $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a command / script in a remote machine () using:

```
ssh <remote_user>@<remote_server> "<command_1>; <command_2>; ... <command_n>"
```

One of these command can be "gftp", a command line FTP client. To download what you need.